Decoding error in encrypt and decrypt fields with frida
I'm new to Frida Hook. In this study, I am trying to get the iv key and string methods. I keep getting errors
I'm trying to solve the encrypt method here.
I would be very happy if you could help me on this issue.

private String encrypt(Key key, AlgorithmParameterSpec algorithmParameterSpec, String str) {
try {
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_AES_GCM_NOPADDING);
  cipher.init(1, key, algorithmParameterSpec);
  return Base64.encodeAsString(cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8")));
 } catch (Exception e2) {
  logger.error("Error in encrypting data. ", e2);
  return null;
 }


Just decompile the code with JadxGui and use the Frida snippet function to generate Frida hooking code you just need to combine into a Frida script.
